# Let $Ω = (0, 1)$, $F = \mathcal{B}((0, 1))$ and $P$ be the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$. Let $X(ω) = − log (ω)$. Find $P_X$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, change-of-variable

I'm solving questions by Athreya: Measure Theory and Probability and I'm stuck in a question:

Let $Ω = (0, 1)$, $F = \mathcal{B}((0, 1))$ and $P$ be the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$. Let $X(ω) = − \log (ω)$, $h(x) = x^2$ and $Y = h(X)$. Find $P_X$ and $P_Y$ and evaluate $E[Y]$ by applying the change of variables formula.

How should I find out $P_X$ in such a case? I know the definition that $P_X(A) = P(X^{-1}(A)) \forall A\in F$ but I'm not sure how to use that in this problem.

Comment: On $(0, 1)$ with Lebesgue measure, the function $t \mapsto t$ has uniform disitribition. Call it $U.$ Then $X$ is defined as $X = -\log U.$

Comment: $P_X((-\infty,t])=P(X\le t)=P({\rm e}^{-X}\ge{\rm e}^{-t})=|\{\omega\in[0,1]:\omega\ge{\rm e}^{-t}\}|$.

Comment: @WilliamM. Then how would P_X be defined ? Also, is it customary to always go through the defintion of the uniform distribution?

Comment: I believe you get an exponential distribution